# Principal curvature of rotationally symmetric body

Tags: differential-geometry

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to find the curvature of a rotationally symmetric particle in spherical coordinates $r(\theta,\phi)=r(\theta)$.
I know how to find the second fundamental form and how to calculate the principal curvatures from the result. But I'm having a few problems with the parameterization.
Unfortunately, I don't have anything close to correct.

Comment: Write down spherical coordinates and use this for $r$.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I could not find any "nice" closed-form equation through this approach. I hoped the symmetry relation might yield a solution through some theorem or equation I have not come across yet.

Comment: The principal curvatures of surfaces of revolution are well-known — the curves $\phi=\text{constant}$ and the curves $z=\text{constant}$. See, for example, pp. 52-53 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.